# Comparing multiple depth buffers

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to use openGL for a project, I was wondering if there was a way to use the built in depth testing with multiple depth buffers. Basically each pass I'm getting a new depth buffer, and I have to compare this with the current depth buffer and write all the values that pass to it. Is there any built in functionality that can do this or will I have to do it manually.

Thanks

Comment: "*each pass*" What do you mean by this? What is being rendered in these passes?

Comment: I do some calculations in a separate part of the program and want to  build up the depth buffer, each calculation will contribute to it and I will render it afterwards. My objective at the moment is just to find a way to build the depth buffer quickly and efficiently.

Comment: Alternatively is there any other format I could put the data in and combine it using the depth test and then read convert it into the correct format later?

Answer (score 0):

It's not mandatory to [clear](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glClear.xml) the depth buffer between pass.

If you don't, For any pass, if a value *succeed* at the depth test it will be writen to the depth buffer.

You can control [the depth function](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glDepthFunc.xml) but possibilities are limited. And the result is always the same: the value is written to the depth buffer (no complicated calculation).

For more complex stuff, you should take a look to [GlSl](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/glsl/).

Finally,  if you want a good help, you should be more specific about your goal.